# C# Accessing Higher-Level Method from Nested Class

Tags: c#, nested-class

I want to create a library class for an external control circuit which communicates via serial port. The circuit has built in functions to get/set various settings using serial communication (e.g. sending "SR,HC,01,1,\r" turns sensor 1 ON). There are ~100 functions sorted into the following categories: Sensor Settings, Output Settings, and Environment Settings. Here is what I tried.

```
public class CircuitController
{
   // Fields.
   private SerialPort controllerSerialPort;
   private SensorSettings sensorSettings;
   private OutputSettings outputSettings;
   private EnvironmentSettings environmentSettings;
   ...

  // Properties.
  // Properties to get sensorSettings, outputSettings, and environmentSettings.

  // Methods.
  public string SendReceive(string sendCommand)   // Send command and receive response.
  {
     ...
  }

  // Nested classes.
  public class SensorSettings
  {
     // Fields.
     // The various sensor settings here.

     // Properties.
     // Properties to get/set the sensor settings. Note: Get/Set is done through calling one of the following methods.

     // Methods.
     public double GetSensorUnits(int sensorNumber)
     {
        ...
        string commandToSend = String.Format("HE,WL,1,{0}", sensorNumber);   // Setup command string.
        string commandResponse = SendReceive(commandToSend);   // Send command and receive response. ERROR here, cannot access higher level, non-static methods.
        // Logic to process commandResponse.
        ...
     }

     // Other methods to create, send, and process the circuit's sensor settings "functions".

  }

  public class OutputSettings
  {
     // Same logic as SensorSettings class.
  }

  public class EnvironmentSettings
  {
     // Same logic as SensorSettings class.
  }
}
```

I figured that this way there won't be 100 methods/properties crammed under the `CircuitController` class. I could use a get property to obtain the sensorSettings instance, for example, and then call the desired method/property: `circuitControllerInstance.GetSensorSettingsProperty.GetSensorUnits(1);`. I receive a compile error that I am trying to access `SendReceive()` from a nested class. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: In case you are interested, Microsoft's Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries has the general advice to avoid public nested types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229027.aspx

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working?

Answer (score 1):

A nested class does not "see" whatever is declared in its host.

You should pass a host reference to any nested class, for instance, in the constructor.